# initialize container in test container before before all

Tags: scala, scalatest, testcontainers

I tried to write a group of tests with a `test container`. Test container needs  to initialize   override `val container = PostgreSQLContainer()` in test class body. I want to make a group of tests which will work with prepared test data inserted to DB. I tried to use `beforeAll` from `org.scalatest`, but it executes before initializing the container and there is an NPE. Could you rewrite code to get correct inserted test data.

```
class MysqlSpec extends FlatSpec with ForAllTestContainer with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override val container = MySQLContainer()
  
  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()

    Class.forName(container.driverClassName)
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(container.jdbcUrl, container.username, container.password)

    // insert some records
    
  }  
  
  "Mysql container" should "be started" in {
    Class.forName(container.driverClassName)
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(container.jdbcUrl, container.username, container.password)

    val prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select 1")
    
    // check the records
  }
}
```

Comment: **TestContainersScala** provides an `afterStart`  & `beforeEnd` methods so you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mixed in the traits in the wrong order. Try `BeforeAndAfterAll with ForAllTestContainer` instead of `ForAllTestContainer with BeforeAndAfterAll`.

Those two traits both override the `run` method and call `super.run` in the process. If you use `ForAllTestContainer with BeforeAndAfterAll`, your class will inherit the `run` method from `BeforeAndAfterAll`, which will call `beforeAll` and then call `super.run`, meaning `ForAllTestContainer`'s `run` implementation, and that will start the container. But you need it to go the other way around, and the order here is controlled by the order of the `with` clauses.

Any more questions as to why implementation inheritance is a bad idea?